# How to replicate objects arriving in Amazon S3 via an AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, replication

I want to replicate few prefixes into another bucket.

I do not want to use the sync and replication service. I want to do it with lambda only and I have ongoing migration running so data is coming in every 20 minutes, no transformation is required.

Can someone help me how I can use AWS Lambda for sync and copy?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a Trigger for an AWS Lambda function so that it is invoked when an object is added to the Amazon S3 bucket. The function will receive information about the object that triggered the function, including its Bucket and Key.

You should code the Lambda function to call `CopyObject()` to copy that object to the desired destination bucket. Here's an example in Python:

```py
import boto3
import urllib

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    TARGET_BUCKET = 'my-target-bucket'

    # Get the bucket and object key from the Event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
    
    # Copy object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_client.copy_object(
        Bucket = TARGET_BUCKET,
        Key = key,
        CopySource= {'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key}
    )
```