# S3 to S3 Cross account data replication

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli, eventtrigger, aws-datasync

I have a S3 bucket in Account A and i want to replicate it to S3 bucket in Account B. I need the whole process along with security measures explained in detail. Starting from how to setup the whole process with VPC and this needs to happen whenever new data is uploaded into S3 bucket in Account A. Deletion in Account A should not be replicated in Account B. I need this for folder and subfolder level as well. I need the cost explanation as well if possible.

Comment: [Configuring replication when source and destination buckets are owned by different accounts - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html) The standard costs for data storage would apply (twice -- once for each bucket) and the objects being replicated would incur standard costs for COPY requests (`$0.005 per 1000 requests`).

Comment: Would we be able to control the destination on a folder and subfolder level? and is this process through the Internet? do we need to unblock the public access for cross account access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Amazon S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html), which can be performed in the same region or between regions, including for buckets belonging to different different AWS Accounts.

See:

You will need to add a Bucket Policy to the *destination bucket* to permit access from the source bucket's AWS Account.

See: [Configuring replication when source and destination buckets are owned by different accounts - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html)

You can control the source Bucket and Prefix (folder) and the destination Bucket. Replication is managed by the Amazon S3 service, there is no need for you to change "S3 Block Public Access" settings.

If the source and destination buckets are in different Regions, then Data Transfer costs will apply.

Comment: Since this is cross account, will the transfer be through internet? How can I control destination prefix, there are no options for that?

Comment: Oops! Looks like you cannot change the destination Prefix, so I have fixed my answer. You can specify a Prefix for the source.

Comment: If the source and destination buckets are in the same Region, then the replication takes place within the AWS infrastructure. It will not go over the Internet. The fact that the buckets belong to different AWS Accounts has no impact on how the data is physically moved.

Comment: Since i cannot control the destination on a folder level. I'm thinking of going for sync using AWS CLI. But can i get instructions on how to set that up? 
I need the steps, bucket policy(limited to working level) both account A & B, IAM roles(limited to working level) both account A & B, Lambda function to trigger copy process and its code, data validation and other necessary codes or steps to be done.

Comment: There is plenty of online information about using AWS CLI between AWS Accounts. For example: [AWS S3 Transfer Between Accounts Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718983/174777) and [Is it possible to copy between AWS accounts using AWS CLI? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263369/is-it-possible-to-copy-between-aws-accounts-using-aws-cli)

Comment: I would not recommend running the AWS CLI via an AWS Lambda function. If you want to use the AWS CLI, then schedule it to run via a cron job on an EC2 instance or any computer on the Internet. Alternatively, you could configure the S3 bucket to trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever a new object is created and you could code the Lambda function to _immediately_ copy that object to a different bucket. So, it isn't a "sync process", it's more of a "copy one object now". See: [How to replicate objects arriving in Amazon S3 via an AWS Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67260033/174777)

Comment: For the first method you suggested, since the frequency of upload is not constant, CRON schedule is not something which is efficient from my POV. As for the second method, is it possible to do for cross account?

Comment: Yes. To perform a cross-account object copy from an AWS Lambda function, simply add a Bucket Policy on the destination bucket that permits `s3:PutObject` for the IAM Role used by the AWS Lambda function. I also suggest you specify `acl=bucket-owner-full-control` as part of the copy to assign ownership of the object to the AWS Account that owns the destination bucket.

Comment: Let us consider a scenario where a wrong data is added to the bucket. Is there a method to identify or validate the data is like in the correct folder? or it will only be know when the ETL process throws error? And i dont know python, what changes other than the bucket name should be changed in that?

Comment: You could code your AWS Lambda function to download and examine the file before performing the copy. Lambda functions can be written in [a variety of languages](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) (not just Python).

Comment: This will be through the internet?

Comment: The AWS Lambda function will make an `copy_objects()` API call. This instructs the Amazon S3 service to copy an object between two buckets (or even within a bucket). This is managed by the S3 service -- your function does not actually download/upload the objects themselves. If the buckets are in different AWS Regions, then the traffic will be sent between regions, either on the AWS network or across the Internet (but always encrypted). If the buckets are in the same region, then it stays entirely within the AWS network.

Comment: hey guys does anyone know how to make the replication run every 6 hours instead of using  "Replica modification sync"?

Comment: The replication traffic won't go over the Internet even if it's cross-region. It'll use Amazon's private network.